# How to use Spring MVC and Spring JdbcTemplate RowCallbackHandler and stream results?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, callback

I currently have a default Spring architecture: Repostiory, Service, Controller (Spring WebMVC), JacksonJson Mapper as "view". All my Repository/Service/Controller methods look like:

```
public Collection<Pet> findPetsWithName(String name) {}
```

So basically each Layer retrieves data, does some calculations and returns it to the next layer.

With increasing Data size I was playing with Spring JdbcTemplate, fetchsize settings and RowCallbackHandler in order to "stream" Database results rather than fetching all at once.

My Question is now: Can I apply the "callback" approach to all layers, not only the Repository layer so that all results are but into a Callback function instread of returning them as Collection? Does it work with SpringMVC views? I think I'd end up with a Chained Callback of :

RowCallbackHandler(ServiceCallbackHandler(ControllerCallbackHandler(SpringViewHandler(HttpSerlvetResponse))))

```
public void findPetsWithName(String name, Callback<Pet> callback) {}
```

Has anyone experiences with this approach? Are there existing Patterns or templates for it? I think there is only a benefit for large data sizes because it is more difficult to design.

Answer (score 0):

The only time I had use for streaming data from row mapper to the response was when we were storing large encrypted binary data in the database and wanted to stream it as-is, to be decrypted by our think client.

Assuming this is the kind of situation you are thinking about, you should use a ResultSetExtractor. 
You can get the stream from the result set in the callback (assuming your data type is blob equivalent), and pipe it to the response output stream, which is accepted as a parameter to your repo method.

Let me know if you are looking to implement a design where each row should be mapped to an object and the call back mechanism should pass the object back to the higher layers one by one.